# Web application could not be started cpanel

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cpanel, whm

I'm installing a rails app on cpanel hosting. I installed Ruby on Rails from Feature Manager in WHM.

Also enabled ruby24-mod_passenger from Easy Apache 4 (in WHM)

Then i added App in Application Manager (in Cpanel)

when i visit from url i saw these error.

I can't find how to solve this.

**Error:**

> Web application could not be started

**Error ID:**

> 7e818f32

**Details:**

```
cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:430:in `activate_gem'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:297:in `block in run_load_path_setup_code'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:435:in `running_bundler'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb:296:in `run_load_path_setup_code'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:100:in `preload_app'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:156:in `<module:App>'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:30:in `<module:PhusionPassenger>'
  /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/helper-scripts/rack-preloader.rb:29:in `<main>'
```

**System information:**

```
Application root
/home/referr12/landing1
Environment (value of RAILS_ENV, RACK_ENV, WSGI_ENV, NODE_ENV and PASSENGER_APP_ENV)
development
Ruby interpreter command
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/libexec/passenger-ruby24
User and groups
uid=1000(referr12) gid=1002(referr12) groups=1002(referr12)
Environment variables
MANPATH = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/man:
HOSTNAME = vps36248.inmotionhosting.com
SHELL = /bin/bash
UNIQUE_ID = Wm7CSit77Nsu4dwPXX6OrAAAAEA
HISTSIZE = 40000
PERL5LIB = /home/referr12/perl5/lib/perl5:
PYTHONUNBUFFERED = 1
RACK_BASE_URI = /landing
PASSENGER_DEBUG_DIR = /tmp/passenger.spawn-debug.XXXXwf1RYv
PERL_MB_OPT = --install_base /home/referr12/perl5
X_SCLS = ea-ruby24 
USER = referr12
LD_LIBRARY_PATH = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64
LS_COLORS = 
RAILS_RELATIVE_URL_ROOT = /landing
IN_PASSENGER = 1
RACK_ENV = development
PASSENGER_USE_FEEDBACK_FD = true
PATH = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/bin:/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/sbin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/home/referr12/perl5/bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/cpanel/3rdparty/lib/path-bin:/usr/local/jdk/bin:/usr/kerberos/sbin:/usr/kerberos/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/root/bin:/opt/bin:/opt/cpanel/composer/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/X11R6/bin:/home/referr12/.local/bin:/home/referr12/bin
MAIL = /var/spool/mail/referr12
WSGI_ENV = development
PWD = /home/referr12/landing1
INPUTRC = /etc/inputrc
JAVA_HOME = /usr/local/jdk
EDITOR = pico
LANG = en_US.UTF-8
NODE_PATH = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/node
TZ = America/Los_Angeles
NODE_ENV = development
SHLVL = 3
HOME = /home/referr12
RAILS_ENV = development
LS_OPTIONS = --color=tty -F -a -b -T 0
PERL_LOCAL_LIB_ROOT = :/home/referr12/perl5
SERVER_SOFTWARE = Apache/2.4.29 (cPanel) OpenSSL/1.0.2n mod_bwlimited/1.4 Phusion_Passenger/5.1.8
LOGNAME = referr12
VISUAL = pico
XDG_DATA_DIRS = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share
CLASSPATH = .:/usr/local/jdk/lib/classes.zip
PKG_CONFIG_PATH = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/pkgconfig
LESSOPEN = ||/usr/bin/lesspipe.sh %s
PASSENGER_APP_ENV = development
RESTARTSRV = 1
HISTTIMEFORMAT = (%m/%d/%y) %T 
PERL_MM_OPT = INSTALL_BASE=/home/referr12/perl5
PASSENGER_BASE_URI = /landing
_ = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/bin/ruby
Ulimits
Unknown
System metrics
------------- General -------------
Kernel version    : 3.10.0-042stab127.2
Uptime            : 1d 13h 33m 29s
Load averages     : 0.19%, 0.10%, 0.02%
Fork rate         : unknown

General Ruby interpreter information
RUBY_VERSION = 2.4.2
RUBY_PLATFORM = x86_64-linux
RUBY_ENGINE = ruby
RubyGems version = 2.6.13
RubyGems paths = ["/home/referr12/.gem/ruby", "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems", "/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/share/gems"]
Ruby configuration (RbConfig::CONFIG)
DESTDIR = 
MAJOR = 2
MINOR = 4
TEENY = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 198
INSTALL = /bin/install -c
EXEEXT = 
prefix = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr
ruby_install_name = ruby
RUBY_INSTALL_NAME = ruby
RUBY_SO_NAME = ruby
exec = exec
ruby_pc = ruby.pc
PACKAGE = ruby
BUILTIN_TRANSSRCS =  enc/trans/newline.c
USE_RUBYGEMS = YES
MANTYPE = doc
NROFF = /usr/bin/nroff
OPTIONAL_PRELUDES = ./abrt_prelude.rb
vendorarchhdrdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include/vendor_ruby/x86_64-linux
sitearchhdrdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include/site_ruby/x86_64-linux
rubyarchhdrdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include
vendorhdrdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include/vendor_ruby
sitehdrdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include/site_ruby
rubyhdrdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include
RUBY_SEARCH_PATH = 
UNIVERSAL_INTS = 
UNIVERSAL_ARCHNAMES = 
configure_args =  '--build=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--host=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' '--program-prefix=' '--disable-dependency-tracking' '--prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr' '--exec-prefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr' '--bindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/bin' '--sbindir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/sbin' '--sysconfdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/etc' '--datadir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share' '--includedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include' '--libdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64' '--libexecdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/libexec' '--localstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/var' '--sharedstatedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/com' '--mandir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/man' '--infodir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/info' '--with-rubylibprefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby' '--with-archlibdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64' '--with-rubyarchprefix=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby' '--with-sitedir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby' '--with-sitearchdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby' '--with-vendordir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby' '--with-vendorarchdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby' '--with-rubyhdrdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include' '--with-rubyarchhdrdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include' '--with-sitearchhdrdir=$(sitehdrdir)/$(arch)' '--with-vendorarchhdrdir=$(vendorhdrdir)/$(arch)' '--with-rubygemsdir=/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems' '--with-ruby-pc=ruby.pc' '--with-compress-debug-sections=no' '--disable-rpath' '--enable-shared' '--with-ruby-version=' '--enable-multiarch' '--with-prelude=./abrt_prelude.rb' 'build_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'host_alias=x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu' 'CFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic' 'LDFLAGS=-Wl,-z,relro ' 'CXXFLAGS=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches   -m64 -mtune=generic'
CONFIGURE = configure
rubygemsdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems
vendorarchdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby
vendorlibdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
vendordir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
sitearchdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby
sitelibdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby
sitedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby
rubyarchdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby
rubylibdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby
ruby_version_dir_name = 
ruby_version = 2.4.0
sitearch = x86_64-linux
arch = x86_64-linux
sitearchincludedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include/x86_64-linux
archincludedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include/x86_64-linux
sitearchlibdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/x86_64-linux
archlibdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64
libdirname = archlibdir
RUBY_EXEC_PREFIX = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr
RUBY_LIB_VERSION = 2.4.0
RUBY_LIB_VERSION_STYLE = 3  /* full */
RI_BASE_NAME = ri
ridir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ri
rubysitearchprefix = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/x86_64-linux/ruby
rubyarchprefix = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby
MAKEFILES = Makefile GNUmakefile
PLATFORM_DIR = 
THREAD_MODEL = pthread
SYMBOL_PREFIX = 
EXPORT_PREFIX = 
COMMON_HEADERS = 
COMMON_MACROS = 
COMMON_LIBS = 
MAINLIBS = 
ENABLE_SHARED = yes
DLDLIBS =  -lc
SOLIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED = -lruby
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -lruby-static
LIBRUBYARG = -lruby
LIBRUBY = libruby.so.2.4.2
LIBRUBY_ALIASES = libruby.so.2.4 libruby.so
LIBRUBY_SO = libruby.so.2.4.2
LIBRUBY_A = libruby-static.a
RUBYW_INSTALL_NAME = 
rubyw_install_name = 
EXTDLDFLAGS = 
EXTLDFLAGS = 
strict_warnflags = -std=gnu99
warnflags = -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format
debugflags = -ggdb3
optflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math
NULLCMD = :
DLNOBJ = dln.o
INSTALL_STATIC_LIBRARY = no
EXECUTABLE_EXTS = 
ARCHFILE = 
LIBRUBY_RELATIVE = no
EXTOUT = .ext
PREP = miniruby
CROSS_COMPILING = no
TEST_RUNNABLE = yes
rubylibprefix = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby
setup = Setup
ENCSTATIC = 
EXTSTATIC = 
STRIP = strip -S -x
TRY_LINK = 
PRELOADENV = LD_PRELOAD
LIBPATHENV = LD_LIBRARY_PATH
RPATHFLAG = 
LIBPATHFLAG =  -L%s
LINK_SO = 
ASMEXT = S
LIBEXT = a
DLEXT2 = 
DLEXT = so
LDSHAREDXX = g++ -shared
LDSHARED = gcc -shared
CCDLFLAGS = -fPIC
STATIC = 
ARCH_FLAG = -m64
DLDFLAGS = -Wl,-z,relro  -m64
ALLOCA = 
codesign = 
POSTLINK = :
WERRORFLAG = -Werror
CHDIR = cd -P
RMALL = rm -fr
RMDIRS = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty -p
RMDIR = rmdir --ignore-fail-on-non-empty
CP = cp
RM = rm -f
PKG_CONFIG = pkg-config
PYTHON = 
DOXYGEN = 
DOT = 
MAKEDIRS = /bin/mkdir -p
MKDIR_P = /bin/mkdir -p
INSTALL_DATA = /bin/install -c -m 644
INSTALL_SCRIPT = /bin/install -c
INSTALL_PROGRAM = /bin/install -c
SET_MAKE = 
LN_S = ln -s
NM = nm
DLLWRAP = 
WINDRES = 
OBJCOPY = :
OBJDUMP = objdump
ASFLAGS = 
AS = as
ARFLAGS = rcD 
AR = ar
RANLIB = ranlib
try_header = 
CC_VERSION_MESSAGE = gcc (GCC) 4.8.2 20140120 (Red Hat 4.8.2-16)
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.
CC_VERSION = gcc --version
CSRCFLAG = 
COUTFLAG = -o 
OUTFLAG = -o 
CPPOUTFILE = -o conftest.i
GNU_LD = yes
LD = ld
GCC = yes
EGREP = /bin/grep -E
GREP = /bin/grep
CPP = gcc -E
CXXFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -mtune=generic
OBJEXT = o
CPPFLAGS =   
LDFLAGS = -L. -Wl,-z,relro -fstack-protector -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic
CFLAGS = -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -mtune=generic -fPIC
CXX = g++
CC = gcc
NACL_LIB_PATH = 
NACL_SDK_VARIANT = 
NACL_SDK_ROOT = 
NACL_TOOLCHAIN = 
target_os = linux
target_vendor = redhat
target_cpu = x86_64
target = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
host_os = linux-gnu
host_vendor = redhat
host_cpu = x86_64
host = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
RUBY_VERSION_NAME = ruby-
RUBYW_BASE_NAME = rubyw
RUBY_BASE_NAME = ruby
build_os = linux-gnu
build_vendor = redhat
build_cpu = x86_64
build = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
RUBY_PROGRAM_VERSION = 2.4.2
cxxflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format
cppflags = 
cflags = -O3 -fno-fast-math -ggdb3 -Wall -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wno-tautological-compare -Wno-parentheses-equality -Wno-constant-logical-operand -Wno-self-assign -Wunused-variable -Wimplicit-int -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration -Wdeprecated-declarations -Wno-packed-bitfield-compat -Wsuggest-attribute=noreturn -Wsuggest-attribute=format
target_alias = 
host_alias = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
build_alias = x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu
LIBS = -lpthread -ldl -lcrypt -lm 
ECHO_T = 
ECHO_N = -n
ECHO_C = 
DEFS = 
mandir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/man
localedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/locale
libdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64
psdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/doc/ruby
pdfdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/doc/ruby
dvidir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/doc/ruby
htmldir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/doc/ruby
infodir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/info
docdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/doc/ruby
oldincludedir = /usr/include
includedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/include
localstatedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/var
sharedstatedir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/com
sysconfdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/etc
datadir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share
datarootdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share
libexecdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/libexec
sbindir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/sbin
bindir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/bin
exec_prefix = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr
PACKAGE_URL = 
PACKAGE_BUGREPORT = 
PACKAGE_STRING = 
PACKAGE_VERSION = 
PACKAGE_TARNAME = 
PACKAGE_NAME = 
PATH_SEPARATOR = :
SHELL = /bin/sh
UNICODE_VERSION = 9.0.0
archdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby
topdir = /opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby
Activated Ruby gems
did_you_mean => 1.1.0
Ruby load path ($LOAD_PATH)
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/share/ruby/site_ruby
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/local/lib64/ruby/site_ruby
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/vendor_ruby
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby
Ruby loaded libraries ($LOADED_FEATURES)
enumerator.so
thread.rb
rational.so
complex.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/enc/encdb.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/enc/trans/transdb.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/unicode_normalize.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/rbconfig.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/compatibility.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/defaults.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/deprecate.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/errors.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/version.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/requirement.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/platform.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/basic_specification.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/stub_specification.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/util/list.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/stringio.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/specification.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/exceptions.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/defaults/operating_system.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/monitor.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/dependency.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/rubygems/rubygems/path_support.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/version.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/core_ext/name_error.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/levenshtein.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/jaro_winkler.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checker.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/delegate.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/class_name_checker.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers/variable_name_checker.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/name_error_checkers.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/method_name_checker.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/spell_checkers/null_checker.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean/formatter.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/gems/gems/did_you_mean-1.1.0/lib/did_you_mean.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/constants.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/etc.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/fileutils.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/tmpdir.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/utils/tmpio.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/platform_info.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/platform_info/operating_system.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/passenger/passenger_native_support.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/native_support.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/socket.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/io/wait.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/socket.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/pathname.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/pathname.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_enhancements.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/ruby_core_io_enhancements.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/base64.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/utils.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/preloader_shared_helpers.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/public_api.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/debug_logging.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/ruby/shellwords.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/utils/shellwords.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/loader_shared_helpers.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/lib64/ruby/fcntl.so
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/message_channel.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/message_client.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/utils/native_support_utils.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/utils/unseekable_socket.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/request_handler/thread_handler.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/request_handler.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/utils/tee_input.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/rack/thread_handler_extension.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core/version.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_core/lib/union_station_hooks_core.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails/version.rb
/opt/cpanel/ea-ruby24/root/usr/share/passenger/phusion_passenger/vendor/union_station_hooks_rails/lib/union_station_hooks_rails.rb
```

Comment: I guess the error states, that you do not have `bundler` installed. I'm not familiar with cpanel, but you may try adding the `bundler` gem the same way you added rails.

Comment: @Magnuss I can't install any thing cpanel do bundler things it self. I think it occurring due to newest version of ruby (2.4) But, I can't find how to downgrade :((

Comment: Looking at [this tutorial](https://documentation.cpanel.net/display/CKB/How+to+Install+Redmine), it shows that you need to install bundler using: `scl enable ea-ruby24 'gem install bundler'`